# Why is a capacitor placed in parallel with oscillator output?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator

I have a circuit board with an oscillator and I'm curious about why there is a capacitor hooked up to the output.  The oscillator is a SWO series HCMOS Square Wave output crystal oscillator.  The schematic of the oscillator connections is as follows.

```
               +3.3V
                |
   ---------    |  C=0.01uF
NC-| 1   4 |---------||-----GND
   |       |
GND| 2   3 |---------->Direct to FPGA input pin
   ---------    |
                |
                = C=15pF
                |
               GND
```

The [data sheet](http://www.mecxtal.com/clock_oscillator.php#XOs) (select H22/H32/H53/SWO) does not reveal much, but there is a "Load" section that says the max load is 15pF.  Specifically, it says:

> Load |   15 pF  ;  ( 30 pF and 50 pF load are also available for +3.3V and +5.0V VDD)

In such a circuit, is the load the capacitor or the FPGA input pin?  If the load is the capacitor, why is the load needed for the oscillator?  What is its purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have a technote paper on this subject, "Effect of Load Capacitance on the Crystal":

http://www.mecxtal.com/pdf/te_notes/tn-021.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The 15 pF load capacitance mentioned in the data sheet is the total load that should be placed on the output - printed circuit track capacitance, input capacitance of the devices it drives, etc.

That capacitor should be removed, it will adversely affect the signal.

Comment: Interesting, the board is from Lattice Semiconductor.  I could easily remove the cap, but what type of adverse affect will it have on the clock signal?  Will it cause delays or deform the clock waveform?

Comment: It would increase the rise and fall times. Perhaps that is the reason for including it.